# std::vector with a variable range does not work

Tags: c++, list

My problem:

when I do this:

```
std::vector<int> pigeonhole[100];
```

it works, but i need a variable here.

when I put this,

```
std::vector<int> pigeonhole(range);
```

the following part fails; it says

> Error expression must have a class type.

```
pigeonhole[arr[i]-min].push_back(arr[i]);
```

same thing with this part: `pigeonhole[i]`

```
void pigeonholeSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    } 

    int range = max - min +1;
    std::vector<int> pigeonhole(range);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      pigeonhole[arr[i]-min].push_back(arr[i]);

    int index = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
       vector<int>::iterator it;
       for (it = pigeonhole[i].begin(); it != pigeonhole[i].end(); ++it)
            arr[index++]  = *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `std::list` is not a `vector`. Read the docs.

Comment: I know...I made a mistake in the title...its now edited.

Comment: `std::list<int> pigeonhole[100]`  Why would you do that when you could do this: `std::vector<std::list<int>> pigeonhole(100);`?   Also, did you really mean to have an array of 100 linked lists?

Comment: std::list<int> pigeonhole[100] this format is fine for my need, but its not always gonna be 100. so in my code I put range which changes everytime I run my program with a different input file.

Comment: @Expert *std::list<int> pigeonhole[100] this format is fine for my need, but its not always gonna be 100.* -- So it isn't fine for your needs if you're going to keep changing that `100` to something else.  That's why I asked previously why you didn't just make it a vector of linked lists, where the `100` can be a variable.

Comment: std::vector<std::list<int>> pigeonhole(range);
if I edit that in my code, is there anything else to be edited to?

 for (it = pigeonhole[i].begin(); it != pigeonhole[i].end(); ++it)
it says: no operator "=" matches these operands
no operator "!=" matches these operands

Comment: When you write `pigeonhole[x].push_back(arr[i]);` it means that `pigeonhole[x]` must be a container that you can push onto. But `pigeonhole[x]` is just an `int`, and you can't push onto that. Maybe you want a vector of vectors or a vector of lists.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is array syntax. `vector` is not an array, it's a class that implements something that looks like an array but is dynamic with a `size()` property amongst others.

```
std::vector<int> pigenhole(100);
```

creates a vector with 100 default-initialized objects of type int.

If you are trying to create 100 vectors of type int, then

```
std::vector<int> pigenhole[100];
```

does this. If what you needed was a dynamic amount of vector, then you want

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> pigenhole;
```

Then you can size it accordingly:

```
pigenhole.resize(10);
pigenhole[0].push_back(1);
```

the above tells `pigenhole` to create 10 vectors, and then it pushes a 1 onto the first of those 10.

Note that the vector class implements `operator[]` so that it can be used in an array-like way

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
std::cout << v[1] << "\n";  // calls v.operator[](2) and prints 2
```

If what you want is a dynamic sized collection of ints, then you need

```
std::vector<int> pigenhole(range);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  pigeonhole[arr[i]-min] = arr[i];
```

`pigenhole` is of type `std::vector<int>` so `pigenhole[n]` returns `int`, not `vector`, in your original code you'd written

```
  pigeonhole[arr[i]-min].push_back(arr[i]);
```

which makes no sense - you're trying to call `push_back` on an `int`.

If you are trying to store multiple values at each outer pigenhole, then you need

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> pigenhole(range);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  pigeonhole[arr[i]-min].push_back(arr[i]);
```

Comment: I have a problem with this part:


     `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)

        {
           std::vector<int>::iterator it;
           for (it = pigeonhole[i].begin(); it != pigeonhole[i].end(); ++it)
                arr[index++]  = *it;

             printf("Sorted order is : ");
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
             printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }`

It prints it all wrong on the console.

sorry no idea how to format this

Comment: how did you compile the code ? I tried to run it on visual studio and gets a lot of errors.

Comment: @Expert It works here with the [online Visual C++ compiler](http://rextester.com/XYIHSD14882).  What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2010

Comment: @Expert Please get the latest version of Visual Studio.  The online compiler uses Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I dont understand this part of the code you did:
for (auto&& hole : pigeonhole) {
  for (auto&& val : hole)

Comment: Those are range-based for loops.  These loops are now part of the C++ language, and more than likely VS 2010 does not support it.

Comment: Also, that first loop to get the minimum and maximum could be replaced with [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element), as [seen here](http://rextester.com/JQY12069)

Comment: @Expert Visual Studio 2010 is 6 years out of date, consider getting the [free Community edition of Visual Studio 15](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) so you can learn modern C++. This is the pre-C++11 version of the same code: http://ideone.com/BovjUL